# Reading recent log entries in zope server

Tags: logging, error-handling, zope

How can I fetch recent log entries(errors) on python script in zope application server.

I noticed a [getLogEntries()](http://apidoc.zope.org/++apidoc++/Code/zope/error/error/ErrorReportingUtility/index.html) method, but don't know how to use it.
Please help.

I tried running the following code.

```
from zope.error.error import ErrorReportingUtility
logs = ErrorReportingUtility.getLogEntries()
```

Got the following error

```
Error Type: Unauthorized
Error Value: import of 'zope.error.error' is unauthorized
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Acquisition:

```
for err in context.error_log.getLogEntries():
    print err
```